# Pixel-wise dryness/wetness frequencies for RasterBrick R

Tags: r, time-series, raster, frequency-analysis

Given a `rasterbrick` `a` with `monthly` time series data of `standardized rainfall` for about 60 years, how can I compute the following on the `rasterbrick` without having to resort to collapsing the data into a `dataframe`:

```
Q = negative/positive number of severely dry/wet months per total months of severely dry/wet events × 100
```

where `severely wet` includes values in the range `1.50 to 1.99` and `severely dry` includes values in the range `−1.99 to −1.50`

I will prefer `Q` to be in `raster` format.  Download the data set and do:

```
dd=spei03_df
dd[1:2]<-dd[2:1]#swap lat and lon
a=rasterFromXYZ(dd)
```

Any thoughts? Thanks.

[Example data set can be found here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnVl_zW00EHegxAprS4s7PDaYQVr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use raster algebra from the `raster` package. Here is an example calculating the severe wet. The final output, `a_wet_perc` is a raster layer with cell values ranging from 0 to 100 (expressed as percentage). You can follow the same logic to create a raster layer summarizing the severe dry condition.

```
library(raster)

# Calculate the Severe Wet
a_wet <- a

# Replace vlaues >= 1.5 and <= 1.99 to 100 
# (Does not need to be 100. A very large number should be good)
a_wet[a_wet >= 1.5 & a_wet <= 1.99] <- 100
# Replace other values to 0
a_wet[a_wet < 100] <- 0
# Replace 100 to 1
a_wet[a_wet == 100] <- 1

# Calculate the percentage of severe wet
a_wet_perc <- mean(a_wet) * 100
```

Comment: this is very insihgtful. Given that `a` has values ranging from `-5 to +5`, when you set `a_dry[a_dry >= 1.5 & a_dry <= 1.99] <- 100`, and all other values `<100 = 0`, isn't this a `severely wet` range? How can one possibly have both `severely wet and severely dry` percentages in one raster? This would be more intuitive in that we can use a diverging color to show wetness and dryness spatially. Any thoughts on this? Thanks again.

Comment: I mis-read your range of severe-dry and severe-wet. I will correct the term from dry to wet in my post.

Comment: As for your second comment. I thought you want two raster layers. One to summarize severe-dry, the other to summarize severe-wet.

Comment: Since now you know how raster algebra works in the `raster` package, just create your own classification to fit your needs.

Comment: Great. Thanks. I will try the `reclassify` function.